# Login with Facebook latest sdk if native app install then dialog not open in android

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am using **latest Facebook-sdk** for Login with Facebook

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
```

Try to login with facebook using `custom button` 
I am also getting this error in `Facebook-android-sdk` github issue https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/580 this issue resolved or not.

I want to open dialog if Facebook native app install, for that first I `logout` using `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()`

I use default login manager like `LoginManager.getInstance()`, then login and logout , but when i check token after logout like this `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` it still exists

Below are my code:

```
callbackManager =
    CallbackManager.Factory.create()

    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance()

LoginManager.getInstance()
    .registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
            val graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.accessToken)
            { jsonObj, _ ->

            }
            val parameters = Bundle()
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email")
            graphRequest.parameters = parameters
            graphRequest.executeAsync()
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
        }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
            var msg = ""

        }
    })
loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(
    this@SignUpActivity,
    listOf("email", "public_profile")
)
```

`Manifest` file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges=
        "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, **I found solution** after lots of research and read many answers.

If your app in **development** mode then generate **Development Key Hash**

**For Windows** use following command:

- Download openSSl from [openssl-for-windows](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads) openssl library and Extract it.
- Create a folder- OpenSSL in C:/ and copy the extracted code there.
- To generate a **development** key hash, run the following command in a command prompt in the **Java SDK folder**
- Change USERNAME with your username
- This command will generate a 28-character key hash unique to your development environment. Copy and paste it into the field of Facebook developer site

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64`

---

If your app in **Release** mode then Generate a **Release Key Hash**

`keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

Hope this save your time...